# Not able to connect / set up one of the Windows machine as Jenkins slave / agent node

Tags: jenkins

**Scenario:**

Both VMs are hosted internally and network connectivity is in place.

1) Master node is running on Centos 7

2) Trying to set up second agent node which is running Windows Server 2012 R2

3) Fixed TCP port for JNLP agents is assigned. That is also allowed through Centos 7 firewall.

4) In fact, another Windows agent node (also running Windows Server 2012 R2) is already connected to master node using similar configuration.

Node Configuration:

Remote root directory : D:\jenkins\workspace

Usage: Use this node as much as possible

Launch method: Launch agent via Java Web Start

**Problem:**

1) When slave-agent is launched using a file from the Windows node, it attempts to connect to host:port (retrying: 11)

2) Error: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to host:port
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

**Troubleshooting:**

1) Just for verification, can ping to each other from master and agent node.

2) Compared the configuration settings with connected agent node.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this issue? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ping is not a verification since win slave uses different port, try to telnet your master to troubleshoot the connection: telnet ip <jnlpport>

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, hopetds. Sadly, the connection failed.

Could not open connection to the host, on po
rt XXXXX: Connect failed

I'll ask our IT Operations / networks team to look into this.

Comment: make sure you also configured windows firewall to allow master-slave connection through jnlp port